# PHP Sending Emails with File Attachments - Email Not Sending At All

Tags: email, attachment, email-attachments, php

After trying to read various articles on sending emails with attachments in PHP (I am use to ASP with VBScript), I wrote the code below. Unfortunately, it does not work at all. Not only does it not send the email with the attachment, the email doesn't seem to send at all, even though my script says that it did send. Where have I gone wrong? I'm not using a form to upload a file. This is a static script.

```
<?php

$EmailTo = "Me@here.com";
$EmailFrom = "You@There.com";
$EmailSubject = "The Email Subject";

$MailBoundary = md5(uniqid(time()));

$Headers = "To: ". $EmailTo . "\r\n";
$Headers .= "From: ". $EmailFrom . "\r\n";
$Headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$Headers .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed;boundary=\"$MailBoundary \"";
$Headers .= "\r\n\r\n";
$Headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.";
$Headers .= "\r\n\r\n";

$FileAttachment = "AttachedFile.pdf";
$File = fopen($FileAttachment, "r");
$FileData = fread($File, filesize($FileAttachment));
$FileData = chunk_split(base64_encode($FileData));
$FileName = basename($FileAttachment);

$EmailBody = "--$MailBoundary\r\n";
$EmailBody .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$EmailBody .= "Content-transfer-encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";

$EmailBody .= "<html>" . chr(13) .
              "<head>" . chr(13) .
              "<style>" . chr(13) .
              ".breg {font-family:arial;font-size:10pt;color:#000000;padding:5px;}" . chr(13) .
              "</style>" . chr(13) .
              "</head>" . chr(13) .
              "<body>" . chr(13) .
              "<div class=" . chr(34) . "breg" . chr(34) . ">" . chr(13) .
              "The message text body goes here" . chr(13) .
              "</div>" . chr(13) .
              "</body>" . chr(13) .
              "</html>";

$EmailBody .= "--$MailBoundary\r\n";


$EmailBody .= "Content-type: " . mime_content_type($File) . "; name=$FileName\r\n";
$EmailBody .= "Content-transfer-encoding:base64\r\n\r\n";
$EmailBody .= $FileData. "\r\n\r\n";

$EmailBody .= " --$MailBoundary--";

if (mail($EmailTo, $EmailSubject, $EmailBody, $Headers))
{
 echo "Email to " . $EmailTo . " has been sent" . chr(13) . "<br />" . chr(13);
}
else
{
 echo "<b>Email to " . $EmailTo . " was not sent</b>" . chr(13) . "<br />" . chr(13);
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried stripping all the extra stuff out, and just sending a minimal email to make sure that the mail call is working properly? If that works, you can slowly add functionality back in until you find the part that stops it working.

Comment: I would stop trying with php mail() its very underpowered, have a look at phpmailer or another calss

Comment: maybe you should use PHPMailer class instead!? google for this one

Comment: Yes, I can just send a basic email. So I know mail() is working

Comment: I have no idea if PHPMailer is available on the server I am working with.

Comment: Do you have any way of looking at the mail logs on the receiving server? Also, do `error_reporting(-1)` in PHP and see if it says anything interesting when you execute it.

Comment: It works for me only when i put the double quotes around charset: `"Content-Type:text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol` - without quotes, there isn't any error, but the mail will be not sent!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
For sending mail with attachment using php mail().Try this code:

<?php

 //If there is no error, send the email
 if(isset($_POST['ur_submit_button_name'])) {
  $EmailTo = "Me@here.com";
  $EmailFrom = "You@There.com";
  $EmailSubject = "The Email Subject";


  $separator = md5(time());

  // carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
  $eol = PHP_EOL;

  // attachment name
  $filename = "ip.zip";//store that zip file in ur root directory
  $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('ip.zip')));

  // main header
  $headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";

  // no more headers after this, we start the body! //

  $body = "--".$separator.$eol;
  $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
  $body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;

  // message
  $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
  $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
  $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
  $body .= $message.$eol;

  // attachment
  $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
  $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
  $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
  $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
  $body .= $attachment.$eol;
  $body .= "--".$separator."--";

  // send message
  if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
  $mail_sent=true;
  echo "mail sent";
  } else {
  $mail_sent=false;
  echo "Error,Mail not sent";

 }
}

?>
```

Comment: mail not send what we have to do .?

Comment: great! It worked for me only after i noticed your double quotes around charset: `"Content-Type:text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol`

Answer (score 0):

i think you have an error in your email content,
generate your email content with imap_mail_compose function:

```
mail('', 'message subject', '', imap_mail_compose(array header, array body));
```